# Cannot install Conda package on DataProc

Tags: conda, dataproc

I'm trying to install a package from Conda Forge while creating a DataProc cluster. My command:

```bash
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name --enable-component-gateway --bucket sandbox --region us-east4 --zone us-east4-a --single-node --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 --master-boot-disk-size 500 --image-version 2.0-debian10 --properties dataproc:conda.packages=jupyter_enterprise_gateway==2.5.2,spark:spark.jars.packages=io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0 --optional-components JUPYTER --max-idle 7200s --project evms-analysis --metadata 'CONDA_CHANNELS=conda-forge'
```

Eventually, this just times out although the cluster is still created. If I use `pip`, the package installs correctly. Is there anywhere I can look (e.g., logs) to see why the Conda method isn't working?

Comment: Not familiar, but [the documented examples](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration#image_version_20) all show specific syntax that this example does not conform to. Namely, the examples imply something like `--properties=^#^dataproc:conda.packages='jupyter_enterprise_gateway==2.5.2'#spark:...`.

Comment: that syntax is for specifying a separator other than commas e.g. if you need multiple jars or packages. Thanks for formatting the question btw!